# Variables "this" context not updating after re-assigning variable

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble defining the proper terminology and if my understanding of the following code is correct.

I create a constructor function

```
function BoardGame () {
    this.count = 10;
    this.random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}

BoardGame.prototype.getNumber = function(){
    // this is a button that is clicked
    $('.inputField').on('click', function (event) {
        this.guess= parseInt($('#inputField').val(), 10);
        $("'#inputField'").val("");
          this.validChecker();
      }.bind(this));
}

BoardGame.prototype.validChecker = function() {
    if (this.guess < 1 || this.guess > 100) {
    $('#warning').append($('<p></p>'));
  }
};

BoardGame.prototype.newGame = function () {
    game = new BoardGame();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    game = new BoardGame();
    game.getNumber();
});
```

In the document.ready function a new instance of a BoardGame is created and the reference is set to the `game` variable in the global scope.

Then, the event listener is created.

When the event listener inside of getNumber is clicked, it passes the "this" context (game) and it uses that as the this reference.  It calls `this.validChecker()`.

At some point, the `game.newGame()` is invoked. Now, a new instance of boardGame is re-assigned to the game variable.  If I look into my "this" references, it references the old BoardGame object (before the re-assignment) not the new BoardGame instance recently created.

If I change my newGame code to this:

```
BoardGame.prototype.newGame = function () {
    BoardGame.call(this);
}
```

And run the newGame function, the "this" references, updates and changes the current object properties to the properties in the BoardGame constructor.  It goes to the actual object instead of re-assigning.  I'm not sure why this makes such a big difference, shouldn't the context of this change to the new assigned object?

When I call new BoardGame() in the newGame function, why doesn't the "this" references change to the new object?

It seems like there is a difference between changing the current object vs re-assigning a new Object, even though I can change properties on the object. What is going on here?

When I call new BoardGame in newGame() and the "this" references the old object after the reassignmnt, what is keeping the reference to the old object, is this a closure? scope? Object by reference vs value concept?

EDIT:  I would like to add that when I "reset" the game var with "new BoardGame()" and then click the button, "this" references the old object. But if I were to call `game.getNumber();` on it's own line, the "this" references the new game object, which is what I expect.

I believe the base of what is happening is related to this example even though I don't have a 100% clear grasp of the concept.

```
var a = {a: "A"};
var b = a;

a = "hello"
b; // still references {a: "A"}
```

So in my scenario, the context of this when the event listener is created is the original object.  Then when `new BoardGame` is called in the newGame function the game references changes but the "this" reference is still referencing the original object (not sure why that doesn't change with it).

When we use the BoardGame.call(this), this refers to only one object in all of the code, no matter where we look.  We aren't ever creating a second object.

Comment: The value of *this* is never a closure (except in ES6 arrow functions, but they're not relevant here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your confusion, hopefully the following helps.

When you call *game.newGame*:

```
BoardGame.prototype.newGame = function () {
    game = new Game();
}
```

All that happens is that a new *BoardGame* instance is assigned to *game*, the previous instance bound to the listener using *bind* has not been altered.

> If I change my newGame code to this:
>
> BoardGame.prototype.newGame = function () {
>       BoardGame.call(this); 
>   }

That calls the constructor as a function and passes the old *game* object to the constructor as *this*. It just updates the properties of the *game* object passed to it, it doesn't create a new one.

> And run the newGame function, the "this" references, updates and
>   changes the current object properties to the properties in the
>   BoardGame constructor. It goes to the actual object instead of
>   re-assigning.

Yes, because you passed the "actual object" as *this*, there is no new object.

> I'm not sure why this makes such a big difference, shouldn't the context of this change to the new assigned object?

*this* is not "context", it's a property of a function's execution context that is set by how you call the function.

It makes a big difference because there is no new object as *BoardGame* wasn't called with *new*, so you're calling it as a function, not a constructor.

*this* is not held in a closure, it is set either by *bind* (in which case it is static) or by how the function is called **on each call**. It is always resolved in the execution context of the current function (ES6 arrow functions change that, but they're not relevant here).

#### Edit

I think you get it from your edit to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am confused about the "on each call". I understand the mechanic, but when I create the newGame with new BoardGame and the game var is reassigned.  When getNumber is clicked on, isn't the object calling it game.getNumber (the game in this scenario would be the new game, that is where the function's "this" is referencing), but it is still referencing the original "game" object.  Is that a result of bind?

Comment: "*…Is that a result of bind*"?. Yes. Objects are passed by reference, you bind the initial *game* object to the listener's *this*. When a new object is assigned to *game*, it does not update the object bound to the listener's *this*, you have to call *bind* again to do that. As in your example, `b = a` means that *a* and *b* reference the same object. Assigning a new value to one (e.g. a = 'foo'` or `b = {}`) doesn't update the other.

Answer (score 0):

Should this portion of your code in the new game function :

```
new Game();
```

read like this instead:

```
new BoardGame();
```

Edit: Never mind. I see you made the change as I was typing.